# Images do not rescale with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have three .svg images that need to resize. For some reason they do not resize, except when the screen is exceptionally small.

html:

```
<div class='au-images'>
    <div class='computer'>
        <p data-sr style='max-width: 180px;'><img src='images/computericon.svg'></p>
    </div>

    <div class='tablet'>
        <p data-sr='wait 0.5s' style='max-width: 180px;'><img src='images/tableticon.svg'></p>
    </div>

    <div class='phone'>
        <p data-sr='wait 1s' style='max-width: 180px;'><img src='images/phoneicon.svg'></p>
    </div>
```

I am also using scroll-reveal, which explains the 'data-sr' tag.

My CSS:

```
.computer,.tablet, .phone {
max-width: 33%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0em 2.5em;
}

.computer img, .tablet img, .phone img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why my images don't resize?

Comment: What result do you expect? How do you want your three images be layouted? Do you want just a row taking the full screen width and containing the images?

Comment: I have three divs, each containing an image. I want the images to align horizontally next to each other, and shrink in size when the window size get smaller. I have a system now that uses .png and media queries, but it looks clunky and doesn't work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't set the `width` on the parent elements of the images. CSS can't calculate a max-width of a max-width, so it uses the max-width of the only width it knows, namely the body.

[Your code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/g2v6ucuy/2/) (modified to show some actual images)

So the solution is to give the parent divs a width instead of a max-width. Since you used padding, I also changed the box sizing to include that.

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 30%;
```

[Updated code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/g2v6ucuy/3/).

Please note that I reduced the width to 30%, because the divs have spaces between them; with 33%, the total width would be 99% plus the width of those two spaces, which may exceed the window.
If you don't want that, remove all whitespace between the inner divs.

[Even more updated fiddle, now using widths of 33.33%](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/g2v6ucuy/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the width unit `vw`. This unit is the **viewport width** expressed in percent. That is `100vw` is the full width of your device.
Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/v929q8mn/1/

```
div.blablabla img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30vw;
}
```

It is supported in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw).